# How can I remap my airplane mode key to a different function on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have got windows 10. How can I change action of airplane mode key on keyboard. For example to turn off my laptop screen?

Comment: What make and model of laptop are you using?

Comment: I'm using HP 255 G6

Comment: You can try using a tool like [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/). It works with most keys, however unfortunately those special keys for turning airplaine mode or screen on and off are none-standard (i.e. do not generate a key code that gets captured by windows) with most manufactures and can not be remapped.

Comment: SharpKeys is not working